# Android dialog set cancel on touch out side

Tags: android, android-dialog, activitygroup

I have this `custom dialog` inside an `Activty` which is inside `ActivityGroup`.

I want the dialog to dismiss when clicked outside, and tried everything i found online to make it work..

I've tried the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` - didn't work

I've tried:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent ( MotionEvent event ) {
  // I only care if the event is an UP action
  if ( event.getAction () == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ) {
    // create a rect for storing the window rect
    Rect r = new Rect ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    // retrieve the windows rect

    this.getWindow ().getDecorView ().getHitRect ( r );
    Log.i(r.toShortString(),r.toShortString());
    // check if the event position is inside the window rect
    boolean intersects = r.contains ( (int) event.getX (), (int) event.getY () );
    // if the event is not inside then we can close the activity
    if ( !intersects ) {
      // close the activity
      this.dismiss ();
      // notify that we consumed this event
      return true;
    }
  }
```

and it didn't work too..

as i see in the LogCat - i think that from some reason **the dialog window size is full screened that why i have no "outside" to touch..**

i think it might have to do something with the activity group.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after lots of thinking i found out the most simple solution:

**The Problem:**

From some reason - although the theme I've used is a dialog and not a full screen display - the `getWindow().getDecorView()` returns a View which covers the whole screen.

**The Solution:**

in my XML file I gave the root element an id and I've changed the function above as follow:

```
private View rootView;

public BaseDialog(Context context, int theme) {
    super(context, theme);  
    //I don't think the next 2 lines are really important - but I've added them for safety  
    setCancelable(true); 
    setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);    
}

public void setRootView(int resourceId)
{
    this.rootView = findViewById(resourceId);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rootView.getHitRect(rect);
    if (!rect.contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
    {
        this.dismiss();
        return true;
    }
    return false;       
}
```

**Hope it will help someone... :)**