# Create a dialog as an actvity?

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my application am create on simple dialog box as an activity.
For change the activity as a dialog using manifest file like

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Dialog_actvity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

this way,it shows dialog correctly,but not able to set the **setcancelable(false)** in the dialog activity.I don't know how to set.Can any one know please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You need to implement this behavior by own. like onbackpress handling or touch handling to close Activity..

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but why have you set `launchMode="singleInstance"`? That probably isn't correct.

Comment: @DavidWasser That attribute is exclusive to activities, I think.

Comment: @Torcellite I know what the attribute is for and what it does. I doubt the OP really needs that here, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @PankajKumar how to set touch handling for the activity.

Comment: @DavidWasser i didn't get any problem with that `launchMode="singleInstance"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549133/android-dialog-set-cancel-on-touch-out-side  read here

Comment: @PankajKumar how to set automatic dismiss for this dialog activity after few seconds.

Comment: implement timertask which will count the given time... and finish the activity. look for AsyncTask or TimerTask

Comment: @PankajKumar am using timer task,but i don't know how to finish that dialog activity.

Comment: show me the code here

Comment: which code you want,dialog activity code.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's an `Activity` and not a `Dialog`, you don't have access to `setcancelable(false)`.
You can disable the back button by overriding `onBackPressed()` in the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Keep in mind, that's little dangerous if you forget to finish your dialog activity in some cases, and it's not really user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to FabiF's answer.. In case the activity also should not automatically close when clicked outside the Activity use:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
{
    return true;
}
```

This won't hinder e.g. your buttons from receiving the click event.